# Dynamically add fields based on select list apex 4.2

Tags: addition, oracle-apex, selectlist, regions

I'm developing in apex 4.2 and currently I'm having some issues with my form.
I want to (dynamically) add textfields/regions based on the number that is selected in a selectlist.

So when  I select 6, i want to see 6 regions with the same kind of textfields in it. 
Now i've made 6 regions myself and I have added some show/hide dynamic actions on it, but isn't there some kind of way to do this without having to manually add regions ?

Comment: Do you have to have regions or could your needs be satisfied with just dynamic text fields?

Comment: I've only learned to use regions, I haven't made dynamic textfields yet, can you explain to me how to make those?

Comment: There are several ways. One is to create a tabular form with a text box field for a column. Another could be to use Javascript/JQuery to copy one text box as many times as needed.  

If you use the tabular form you will end up with a posted value in an array such as apex_application.g_f01.  

If you were to make copies of say P1_TEXTBOX item then the way it gets posted to the server end up being a string delimited by colons. This is the same way the sever handles multi-select items like Checkboxes and Shuttles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a process on your page when a button is pressed and run this PL/SQL anonymous procedure

```
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..limit LOOP
APEX_ITEM.TEXT(P_IDX        => 1,
   p_value      =>'array element '||i ,
   p_size       =>32,
   p_maxlength  =>32);
END LOOP;
END;
```

the variable "limit" is catched from you're select list.
this example is for creating textfileds dynamicaly althougth you can what ever item you want from the APEX_ITEM API , so here is the link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/apex_item.htm#AEAPI192.